# Bundle Resource Images Into One Exe?

Tags: vb.net, resources, exe

I'm new to resources with coding. I just want to create a standalone exe that has a couple of png images bundled inside of it.

Is there a way to do this? I have tried setting the build action of the images to embedded resource but when the program is compiled there seems to be no exe at all. I'm sure there's a simple way that this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `My.Resources`.  Don't add the image files to the project in the Solution Explorer yourself.  Open the project properties and add the files on the Resources page.  If you add Image1.png and Image2.png then you can access them in code using `My.Resources.Image1` and `My.Resources.Image2`.  You don't have to do anything extra.